# How to dry out the inside of a bicycle frame?

Tags: maintenance, preventative-maintenance

I have a bicycle with a high carbon steel frame. For the most part, this frame is sealed off from the air, but there are some bolts, through which water can get through during rainy days or when washing the bicycle. I am concerned this could cause rust.

Is there a method by which to dry the interior of the bicycle out, to avoid rust?

Comment: There is anti rust stuff you can pour in.  I remove the seat post and hang upside down.

Comment: Quality Steel frames only suffer from cosmetic rust.  If worried, use 'frame saver' and ensure there is a breather hole (Usually under the bottom bracket). If you can be bothered, pull the seat post out if you think there is water in the frame.

Comment: The one place where I worry about rust in a standard steel frame is the bottom bracket.  The solution there is to 1) remove the shaft assembly and thoroughly coat every surface with grease, and 2) keep the drain hole at the bottom of the BB housing clear.

Comment: Aside - One way to minimise water ingress is to store your bike out of the rain, and ideally somewhere that its not cold and damp.  Parking it inside the house in winter is a good way to help dry it off.

Comment: ... and don't wash your bike with a hose! Use wet rags.

Answer (score 8):

The most important thing to do to keep the inside dry and prevent excess rust is a proper drain hole on  the underside of the bottom bracket. Outside of issues with heavily salted roads, drain holes are enough to prevent meaningful rust. The next step is something like Weigle framesaver, or just a blast of aerosol lube every couple years in each tube. Framesaver is great against salted roads, but otherwise is usually overkill.